# Output numbers separated by commas

Tags: c#

This is a question given to me in my class:

Write a *for* loop that prints 1 through n, separated by commas. Example: for n = 9 print
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

My code is.

```
for (int number = 1; number <= 9; number++)
    Console.Write("{0},", number);
Console.ReadLine();
```

It outputs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
Is there a way to print it without the comma after the 9?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you thought about using `if` statements?

Comment: Yes.  I can think of at least 4 ways.  1) Check to see if the value is a `9`, 2) build up a string and conditionally add a comma 3) build a list of values and use `string.Join`, 4) build up a string and conditionally _remove_ the last comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is by printing out the first number, and then in each iteration print out a comma followed by the next number. That way a comma isn't at the end.

```
Console.Write("1");
for (int number = 2; number <= 9; number++)
  Console.Write(", {0}", number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending your method you could use the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) and do something like this:

```
int maxNumber = 9;
for (int number = 1; number <= maxNumber; number++)
{
    Console.Write(number != maxNumber ? "{0}," : "{0}", number);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Another, more concise option using [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) is:

```
int maxNumber = 9;
Console.Write(String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, maxNumber)));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: [Useful for explaining what ternary operators are](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: @PremierBromanov Thanks, I've added the reference to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility, assuming you are required to use a `for` loop for the exercise.

```
int count = 9; string result = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) result += i.ToString(i < count ? @"#\," : "#");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 9)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine what the value for n will be first:

```
Console.Write("Please insert max value: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

now you can use a for loop for outputting the numbers:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ", ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple logic to print without comma at the end
Example : 2, 4, 6, 8, 10

```
namespace PurushLogics
{
    class Purush_EvenNoOddNo
    {

        //Print Even Number & Odd Numbers , seperated
        static void Main()
        {

            int start = 50;
            int end = 100;

            for (int j = start; j <= end; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(j);
                    if (j < end) // To avoid print , at the end
                    {
                        Console.Write(",");
                    }

                }
            } Console.WriteLine();
            for (int j = start; j <= end; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(j);
                    if (j < end-1)
                    {
                        Console.Write(",");// To avoid print , at the end
                    }

                }
            } Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple, yet perhaps not the most optimized may is to store your out message in a string, and clip off the end.

```
string output = ""; //empty string
for (int number = 1; number <= 9; number++)
    string += number.ToString() + ","; //you can add strings together with '+'. 

output = output.Substring(0, output.length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(output);
Console.ReadLine();
```

my c# is a little rusty

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) is a reference for `Substring()`

Answer (score -1):

You can use list too instead of Array.
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Array));